# R (read_csv2) converts column to logical and replaces values with NAs in unbalanced dataset

Tags: r, readr

I have a csv file with 24 columns and 271,691 rows that I read into R like this:

```
df <- read_csv2("C:/FinData/Testfile.csv")
```

Everything works fine except for one column that R converts to col_logical() even though it contains 44 cells with numerical values. Converting to numeric afterwards doesn't help as every value has been replaced by NA.

This is the error message I get:

> Using ',' as decimal and '.' as grouping mark. Use read_delim() for
>   more control. Parsed with column specification: cols(   .default =
>   col_double(),   Id = col_character(),   Assets = col_logical() ) See
>   spec(...) for full column specifications. Warning: 44 parsing
>   failures.
>
> row   col      expected            actual  file
>   9961 Assets    1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE -162473 'C:/FinData/Testfile.csv'

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I get R to recognize the column as a numeric column and keep the values? Other columns, with almost as many NAs, get read in as col_double() just fine.

I apologize for not creating a reproducible example but I have no idea how to do it in this case…

Thanks!

Comment: Always specify the package you are using. See `?readr::read_csv`, section `Arguments`, `col_types` argument: `If ‘NULL’, all column types will be imputed from the first
          1000 rows on the input. This is convenient (and fast), but
          not robust. If the imputation fails, you'll need to supply
          the correct types yourself.`

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't noticed the "imputed from the first 1000 rows" part. If you change your comment to an answer I will mark it as solved.